# How to delete bone driver fmodifiergenerator

Tags: scripting

my problem started when i tried to add a driver to a single bone in pose mode. That part is already solved and it was successful. The problem is 'that' script added an Fmodifiergenerator, i need your help to remove this generator with python in blender 2.74. I have seen another answers on this site on this subject. I tried it all and it doesnt work on my problem. I'm not looking for a fancy solution that will removed it from every bone in the armature, i'm just looking for a simple solution that will remove it from the specific bone that had been added with the driver_add script.
This is the script that i used to add the driver

```
#add driver
driver = bpy.context.object.pose.bones['Bone.001'].driver_add('rotation_euler', 2).driver

driver.type = "SCRIPTED"
#add variable
var = driver.variables.get("var", driver.variables.new())

var.name ='var'

Var.type = 'TRANSFORMS'

#add target

target = var.targets[0]

target.id = bpy.data.objects.get('armature.001')

target.bone_target = "bonectrl"

target.transform_space = 'TRANSFORM_SPACE'

target.transform_type = 'LOC_Z'

#add expression = "var*50"
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some commented console code using [FCurveModifier.remove(...)](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.FCurveModifiers.html?highlight=fcurvemodifier#bpy.types.FCurveModifiers.remove) I have a location.x driver on the context object's pose bone "Bone", which has an fcurve generator modifier.

```
>>> driver = C.object.animation_data.drivers[0]
# driver 0 is driving location.x of pose bone "Bone"
>>> driver.data_path
'pose.bones["Bone"].location'

>>> driver.array_index
0
# if len(driver.modifiers) or somesuch
>>> mod = driver.modifiers[0]
>>> mod
bpy.data.objects['Armature']...FModifierGenerator
# yep it's a GENERATOR
>>> mod.type
'GENERATOR'
# remove it.
>>> driver.modifiers.remove(mod)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it's not quite there yet. When i tried your script, it failed when reaching driver.data_path. It replied to other bone in the armature when i traced it on python console, not the one i've just added driver on. I've added the script that i use to add details on my work. Please help me once more.

Comment: Given the new info, use something like `driver = C.object.animation_data.drivers.find('pose.bones["Bone.001"].rotation_euler', 2)` to find the driver.

Comment: Sorry, still failed. It came back with an error "type error: find() takes exactly one argument (2 given)"

Comment: [AnimDataDrivers.find](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.AnimDataDrivers.html#bpy.types.AnimDataDrivers.find) might need `..drivers.find("blah", index=0)` however works fine for me on 2.79 without.   Maybe it's different in 2.74, certainly not going to bother getting 2.74 to check.  [Yep from docs it's not there](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bpy.types.AnimDataDrivers.html#bpy.types.AnimDataDrivers.find) There are plenty of other ways to get the driver you want from list with for and if statements etc.. or upgrade.

Comment: Hey batFINGER, sorry to bother you again, could you please help me with this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88303/python-how-to-snap-pose-bones-to-cursor.